# How to see/update database version? Is there something like "fallbackToDestructiveMigration"?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

After modifying the **sq** file by renaming one of the tables and adding one more table I didn't find any place to specify that database schema or version has been changed and I want no migration - just recreate database. The documentation on [official website](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/multiplatform_sqlite/migrations/) does not contain any information about this.

Project compiles but when I run the app on both Android and iOS I get a runtime crash and in logs it says that added table does not exist.

I tried adding version in build.gradle.kts of shared module but I still get runtime crash:

```
sqldelight {
   database("MyDatabase") {
      packageName = "com.example.shared.cache"
      version = 2 // added this line only
   }
}
```

I don't want to delete and reinstall the app. Ideal solution would be something like [fallbackToDestructiveMigration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbackToDestructiveMigration()) Room database has

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/1213) about a destructive migration. Last comment suggests to handle that in platform specific drivers but it doesn't show how to do that.

So my questions are:

1. How to change the database version?
2. How to setup destructive migration?

I wish documentation was more detailed on various topics. It would make finding right information easier for developers like me who is not very experienced in Sqlite.

Comment: As destructive migration is still not supported, do you wanna help in how to do a migration or  not? The question title say 'yup' but the question body seems to say 'nope'.

Comment: Sorry for confusion :) Well if we don't have destructive migration yet, my guess is that proper migration is the only solution. I would appreciate if you could show how to do it.

Comment: To make things more clear: what I tried to say in the question was that I want to set up destructive migration, but to trigger it I need to find a place where I could see current db scheme version (I think by default it is 1) and hence modify it. For normal migration I still need to change the scheme version. And I could not find any example of how to do that. I also don't know how the complete process of migration looks like.

Comment: @shadowsheep I saw your answer and tried it out today. I faced some issues with gradle but I was able to get migration working by following instructions in your post. I wanted to accept it now and saw that it was removed. If you will post it again I would gladly accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Marat. I've removed it 'cause I thought you would consider a different answer, leaving space for it. But if you've found it helpful, I'm glad to put it back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While waiting for a destructive migration, let’s follow the current migration docs.

The [official](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/multiplatform_sqlite/migrations/) docs it's quite well written.

> The .sq file always describes how to create the latest schema in an
> empty database. If your database is currently on an earlier version,
> migration files bring those databases up-to-date

This means that if you change your original `.sq` file (database version 1), then if you want to *migrate* the already created databases in devices to the new version (version 2) you must write a `1.sqm` file in which you add all the difference between version 1 and version 2.

Let's say your origial (first app release) db was created by

`MyDb.sq` :

```
-- src/main/sqldelight/com/example/sqldelight/MyDb.sq

CREATE TABLE Foo (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  foo TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Foo (foo)
VALUES ('bar');
```

This is said to be the version 1 of your db.

Now let's say you want to add a table and change the previous one, you have to change your `MyDb.sq` file accordingly for a newly database created in a new app fresh install, but you need also to add a `1.sqm` (the number **1** is the db version to upgrade to the subsequent version — in this case 2) to migrate your existing original db in your current app installations.

`MyDb.sq` :

```
-- src/main/sqldelight/com/example/sqldelight/MyDb.sq

CREATE TABLE Foo (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  foo TEXT NOT NULL,
  bar TEXT
);

INSERT INTO foo (foo, bar)
VALUES ('bar', 'beer');

CREATE TABLE Beer (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  brew TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

`1.sqm` :

```
-- src/main/sqldelight/com/example/sqldelight/2.sqm

ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar TEXT;

CREATE TABLE Beer (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  brew TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

If you extract your original db from one device you can put it along with these two files and named it `1.db`. Or you can

> generate a .db file from your latest schema, run the
> generateSqlDelightSchema task, which is available once you specify a
> schemaOutputDirectory, as described in the gradle.md. You should
> probably do this before you create your first migration.

Doing that you can validate the migration with the gradle task `verifySqlDelightMigration` . This task gives you errors if you wrote a wrong migration. It will be successful for a good migration instead.

Comment: I had some follow-up questions about some steps in migration. I hope you don't mind if I write them here in the comments. I will appreciate any help. As I understood overall process looks like: 1) `create 1.db file` 2) `modify database` 3) `create 1.sqm file` 4) `create 2.db` 5) `run verifySqlDelightMigration task`. Did I get it right?

Comment: Should I always keep all `sqm` and `db` files? I think yes because I can never be sure that all of the app users have updated the app to latest version. Is that correct way of thinking?

Comment: I have almost no experience with gradle outside of default and basic usecases. When creating `.db` file, after specifying `schemaOutputDirectory` I went to terminal tab and run `./gradlew tasks`. There I saw under SQLDelight section there are 5 `generateXXXSchema` tasks but no task named exactly `generateSqlDelightSchema`. I took the first that I saw - `generateAndroidDebugMyDatabaseSchema` and it created `.db` file. Is this enough or should I run all 5 separately? Or is these all wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's right to keep all files for a complete migration of an original db. I did it (I'm actually on version 3 of my db). To be honest I always take the db directly from one of my devices, also to keep a look inside of it (on macOS I use DB Browser for SQLite application) and I use it directly by copying and pasting it.

Comment: Anyway I see that all `generateXXXSchema` preduce the same `*.db` file in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As the [official](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/multiplatform_sqlite/migrations/) documentation doesn't support a rule such as [fallbackToDestructiveMigration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbackToDestructiveMigration()), we will need to delete table/database and create it again.

Following the documentation, you will need first, as you mentioned, increment the version number

```
sqldelight {
  database("MyDatabase") {
    packageName = "com.example.shared.cache"
    version = 2 // added this line only
  }
}
```

After that, you will need to create a file `1.sqm` to "migrate" from previous version (version 1) to current version (version 2). On this file, first, we will remove the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;
```

or remove database:

```
DROP DATABASE MyDatabase;
```

And then, bellow this line, we will create the table again:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
)
```

Or the database and its tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
)
```