# using string as id

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, sqldelight

I am making a KMM app using SQLDelight for the cache and recently I changed my database entities to use Text(String) for the id field instead of Int, now i am getting an error when inserting, I might just be missing some sqlDelight knowledge

here is my table:

```
 CREATE TABLE sidework_Entity(
   id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   employees TEXT NOT NULL,
   todoToday INTEGER AS Boolean DEFAULT 0
);
```

here is my insert method:

```
insertSidework:
INSERT OR REPLACE
INTO sidework_Entity(
       id,
       name,
       employees,
       todoToday
) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

here is my error:

```
statement aborts at 5: [INSERT OR REPLACE
    INTO sidework_Entity(
           id,
           name,
           employees,
           todoToday
    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?)] datatype mismatch
```

I think it is most likely the Primary Key i have set on the id field or something of that sort but the documentation is a bit short.

Comment: turns out i just needed to clean app and delete the old app from my device before re running, most likely the old db table where I had the id as int was still lurking in there somewhere. thanks anyways guys

Comment: check out [how](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/jvm_sqlite/migrations/) you can run migration, in case you don't wanna ask user to reinstall the app when your DB is changed

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is actually running a migration. Although deleting the app to clear the database cache is a valid solution for testing purposes. For an app in production, this isn't the correct approach.

[Documentation for running Migration](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/jvm_sqlite/migrations/)

[Stackoverflow answer with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65211389/13533028)